# Submit button confirm for delete not working in rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, submit, destroy

I'm still new to rails and trying to understand something when deleting multiple items.  When I click submit, it works and I can delete multiple items, however, it deletes regardless of my confirmation response.

I am using javascript to detect onclick event of my submit button, my code is:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    checked = countChecked();
    if (checked > 1) {
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete these ' + checked + ' entries?');
    } else {
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');
    };
});
```

My submit button is:

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete Selected", { :class => 'delete'} %>
```

Why is the confirmation not doing the right thing?  It deletes even if I press cancel...

Comment: The confirm() returns True if you press OK and False if you press cancel. you are doing nothing with the value returned by confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    checked = countChecked();
    if (checked > 1) {
       return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete these ' + checked + ' entries?');
    } else {
       return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');
    };
});
```

Comment: no its not actually (i thought so too haha), he returns the confirm response... i have to wait a few more minutes to accept your answer haha, thanks!